# How do I create alias for AWS or create SSH config file for connecting Amazon using SSH?

Tags: ssh, alias, aws

I'm trying to create an alias in order to SSH to an Amazon AWS EC2 Instance in an easy and faster way. I have tried:

```
alias amazon="ssh -o IdentityFile=~/home/user/Desktop/AWS Machines/file.pem dns.compute.amazonaws.com"
```

But I keep getting:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname machines/file.pem: Name or service not known
```

How do I create that successfully?

Answer (score 1):

This path has spaces and you are using a relative path, it is recommended to use an absolute path:

```
IdentityFile=~/home/user/Desktop/AWS Machines/file.pem
```

The correct way should be:

```
IdentityFile="/home/user/Desktop/AWS Machines/file.pem"
```

In case you want to use a relative path, this symbol `~` points to `/home/your_current_user`, so the path will be:

```
IdentityFile="~/Desktop/AWS Machines/file.pem"
```

Answer (score 1):

An appropriate `~/.ssh/config` entry might be:

```
Host amazon
    Hostname        your_ec2_instance.compute.amazonaws.com
    IdentityFile    "/home/your_user/Desktop/AWS Machines/private_key.pem"
```

You should then be able to connect simply using:

```
ssh amazon
```

Comment: it does not work and when i run ssh amazon replay is ( ssh: Could not resolve hostname amazon: Temporary failure in name resolution )

Comment: i think it has some problems because of permissions  (-r-------- ) - pem file